# TFS ant build script - Permission denied

Tags: ant, tfs

I have used the following to give the tfs credentials and then execute tf command in my ant script.

```
                  <arg value="-login:${tfs.username},${tfs.password}"/>               
                  <arg value="-new"/>            
                  <arg value="-noprompt"/>               
                  <!--arg value="-computer:${computer.hostname}"/>-->
                <arg value="copy"/>
                <arg value="message"/>
                <arg value="Tagging ${build.number} build version"/>
                <arg value="${tfsroot}/WMS/branches/${branch}"/>
                <arg value="${tfsroot}/WMS/tags/BUILD_${build.number}"/>
            </exec>
```

I have used almost all the credentials which I use in my team foundation from eclipse to connect to the tfs.

But ,tfs is rejecting everything and throwing me this error.

/opt/UPS/CWARE/data/wms_builds/scripts/wms_test_maint_tfs:1332: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "tf": java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied

Please advice, if i am on right path in setting these credentials for tfs

Comment: Which tf command are your using? Suppose your account are lack of the permission of the `tf command` that you are running.

Answer (score 1):

And to get tf.exe, you need to install Team Explorer. The version of Team Explorer should matches the version of TFS you are using. (e.g. if you're using TFS 2015 then install Team Explorer 2015.)

There is a Java TFS client in the Team Explorer Everywhere installation (together with an Eclipse plugin). Look at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30661